# How to call End point URL in List custom settings into salesforce

Tags: callout, customsetting

I have created URL(End point url) in custom settings object name 'History' to call end-point url  in soap callout controller.How to call that url  in apex controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getAll()` or `getInstance()` method to get the list custom setting in your apex class.You can also write a SOQL query on your custom settings.